# Awstats / webalizer alike for IIS 7.5

Tags: iis, awstats, webalizer

I have a few websites running purely on IIS7.5 (created in ASP.NET), and I would like to have some statistics over them.

Now I used to have webalizer and awstats as a after-log-analyze utility but it's old and I rather don't want to install extra junk on my production servers.

Are there any log analyze tools available that can generate reports for IIS? Or am I stuck with google analytics like apps.

I am aware that webalizer generates plain HTML files, but I would like something more interactive than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out SmarterStats (www.smarterstats.com).  As a vendor, they are great, and SmarterStats is excellent.  For a single domain it's free (but not clustered logs with the free version), and for multiple sites it's affordable.

[AWStats](http://www.awstats.org/) is another free option to consider, but not as rich as SmarterStats.